# Log File Not Found - Mule Server Installation

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-module-jpa

I am installing Mule Server (Version 3.6.1) on Windows Server R2. I have already set the JAVA_HOME to proper location.

On running `startup.bat`, it encounter following error:

```
File not found - MULE-ENTERPRISE-3.6.1\LOGS\MULE_EE.LOG
```

Any help?

**Update 1**

```
Could not find the main class: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.  Program
 will exit.
Could Not Find C:\mule\mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.6.1\mule-enterpris
e-3.6.1\logs\mule_ee.log
MULE_HOME is set to C:\mule\mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.6.1\mule-ente
rprise-3.6.1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/codehaus/
groovy/tools/GroovyStarter : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
1)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.  Program
 will exit.
File not found - MULE-ENTERPRISE-3.6.1\LOGS\MULE_EE.LOG
File not found - MULE-ENTERPRISE-3.6.1\LOGS\MULE_EE.LOG
File not found - MULE-ENTERPRISE-3.6.1\LOGS\MULE_EE.LOG
File not found - MULE-ENTERPRISE-3.6.1\LOGS\MULE_EE.LOG
File not found - MULE-ENTERPRISE-3.6.1\LOGS\MULE_EE.LOG
```

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid as you suggested I have updated question with the error message. The file not found message keeps repeating infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your JRE version to minimum 1.7.0_60 (or above); as this is what is required for Groovy.

Please upgrade to the [latest supported version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html) and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Close the mule_ee.log file if opened or ctrl-c if you are running "tail -f" on this file. This has resolved the issue for me.

The JRE mismatch issue is also observed in your logs, which is not directly related to `File not found - MULE-ENTERPRISE-3.6.1\LOGS\MULE_EE.LOG`

What is not clear is this issue doesn't always happen when the file is opened or tailed. Maybe it has something to do with when the file being rolled over during the startup.